# Logging an error with offset().top, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to determine the top offset of an element and the console logs an error, even though JQuery's documentation says it should be written like this:

```
$('.myObject').offset().top
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Why does this happen?
Any solution for the problem?

Comment: what does $('.myObject').length returns?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `$('#myObject')`? Using a class selector may be returning a set instead of one element.

Comment: If called on a set, .offset() will return the offset of the first element so it should not crash anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually happens because `$('.myObject')` returns nothing. To protect your code from crashing, check if the element exists before calling `.offset().top`

```
var myObj = $('.myObject');
if (myObj.length){
   myObj.offset().top
}
```

Since `.top` is a *property* and not a *method*, it is not handled by jQuery and, hence, will crash your script if it is not existing.

Comment: Slight optimization: do `var myObject= $('.myObject');` and then use `myObject`. This prevents jQuery from having to traverse the DOM twice, which is relatively very expensive.

Comment: Even thou optimization was out of the scope of the question (and my answer) I've updated accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I think your update had a race condition with zzlalani, and you lost your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check if the element exists.

e.g.

```
var myObjExists = $('.myObject').length > 0 ? true : false;
```

if you then `console.log(myObjExists);`, it should return true or false.

From here you can do some errorhandling to why it does not exist.

If you need more details, please also post the HTML that this code points to.